# Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' to 'name.mainVC' - signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm very new to coding and trying to make an onboarding screen. I use 3 screens in my Onboarding storyboard and they work fine until I try to switch storyboards. It shows me 'Signal SIGABRT' in the line

```
let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainVC") as! mainVC
```

Error:

> 2020-02-25 13:19:17.128892+0100 ihopeyoureokay[89853:2434827]
>   [Storyboard] Unknown class mainVC in Interface Builder file. Could not
>   cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x110a5b940) to
>   'ihopeyoureokay.mainVC' (0x1060cc918). 2020-02-25 13:19:17.129648+0100
>   ihopeyoureokay[89853:2434827] Could not cast value of type
>   'UIViewController' (0x110a5b940) to 'ihopeyoureokay.mainVC'
>   (0x1060cc918).

My full code in this file is:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func Gotoactual(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "actual", bundle: nil)
        let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainVC") as! mainVC
               self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and my sceneDelegate looks like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunched")
        let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "actual", bundle: nil)

        var vc: UIViewController

        if launchedBefore {
            vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        } else {
            vc = launchStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "firststoryboard")
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunched")

        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
}
```

Here also another screenshot that could maybe help:
[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your inspector, select your viewcontroller and check that must be as below:
[image: this]

The  `as! mainVC` required you are have a class named `mainVC`

Also you are not need to create two different storyboards, instated you can create a two different controllers, and make your view controller according to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Put storyboard id as `mainVC` to get the code running!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use `SceneDelegate.swift` if you are not using `SwiftUI`. You should do following:

- Make sure you have a storyboard named `actual.storyboard`.
- Set `MainViewController` storyboard id to `mainVC` in property navigator.
- Don't use force unwrap, use `guard let` or `if let` statements.

Here is a sample code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func goToActual(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "actual", bundle: Bundle(for: MainViewController.self))
        guard let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainVC") as? MainViewController else {
            print("Failed to get MainViewController instance!")
            return
        }
        self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had my storyboard id to mainVC but changing it to guard let helped! thank you so much